# Google Maps Dynamically Change Info window

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Pretty straight forward question about google maps API v3.

I am wanting to change the text on the click event of the a> tag. That works fine but when the infowindow closes and reopens, the text is reset.

**Conditions:** There will be multiple markers on the map.

**Here is the code where I am defining the marker its actually called in a For Loop (didnt post that):**

```
contentString = 
    '<div id="infoContent">' +
    '<div id="siteNotice">' +
    '<h4 id="firstHeading" class="firstHeading">Store ' + 
    Store[x].StoreNumber + 
    ' - ' + 
    Store[x].Location + 
    '</h4>' +
    '<div id="bodyContent">' +
    '<ul>' +                          
    '<li><a onclick = "addDispatch(this,' + Store[x].DailyDispatchID +')"> Add </a></li>' +
    '</ul>' +
    '</div></div>';


infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: contentString
});

bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infowindow, contentString)

function bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infowindow, strDescription) {            
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
        infowindow.setContent(strDescription);
            infowindow.open(map, marker);
        });
    }
```

**As you can see, in the content string, I defined an onclick event that calls 'addDispatch'. The function is here:**

```
function addDispatch(element, DispatchId) {            
    if (element.text == "Add") {
        $(element).text("Remove");
    } else {
        debugger;
        $(element).text("Add");
    }            
}
```

It works fine to change the text, but once I re-open the infowindow, it goes back to default.

Anyone have any ideas?

I'm guessing its because the event handler is bound to the content string of the marker window.

I've searched all up and down and can't quite find a solution for this. Thanks in advanced.

(Excuse the debugger code)

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle?

Comment: Yeah lemme do that real quick.

Comment: Can't 100% replicate because of jsfiddle restrictions, but this is close enough: http://jsfiddle.net/TcwwD/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use a string as `content` this string will be parsed each time you open the InfoWindow.

The DOMNode that will be created based on your content-property will be discarded when you close the InfoWindow.

**Solution:** use a Node instead of a string as content-property. Changes that have been applied to this Node will be permanent(when you close the InfoWindow the Node will be detached from the document, but he  still exists and will be used as content again when you open the InfoWindow the next time)

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/TLs8P/

Comment: Hi @Dr.Molle
I want to do different of Botonomous.
I have an ionic app, where the users have to fill a form  for the informations appear in the infowindow.
The problem is if the same user fill the form with new informations, the new informations doesn't appears, just the last informations keep in the infowidow! How to change it?
Thank you for your help.

Comment: @GustavoSevero: can you provide a demo/link

Comment: I can send my codes, but a demo I don't have to share.
Send me an email and I reply with the codes, OK?
gustavo.msevero@gmail.com